# Angular 4 : If there are multiple components with same selector, how to load only one component based on some condition?

Tags: angular, typescript

Main component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '<app-report></app-report>'
})
```

Component 1:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-report',
    templateUrl: './trip.report.html'
})
```

Component2 :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-report',
    templateUrl: './user.report.html'
})
```

Is there any way in angular 4, through which based on some condition which component (component 1 or 2) will be loaded in "main component" based on some condition?

Comment: I wonder in this specific case why would you name them the same, considering that only by looking at the template names they are related to completely different elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to do that. Selectors need to be unique for all components and directives declared within and imported into a single `NgModule`.

If you own the code, just don't create conflicting selectors.

If imported 3rd-party modules have components with conflicting selectors,
you can wrap a conflicting component in another component with a non-conflicting selector and add it to it's own module.
Then you can specify in `@NgModule({imports: [...]})` which component should be used.

Then you can just use `*ngIf`

```xml
<conflicting-component *ngIf="foo"></conflicting-component>
<de-conflicted-wrapper *ngIf="!foo"></de-conflicted-wrapper>
```

Comment: can you explain more on your approach?