# Ngx-Bootstrap Popover and Ngx-popover name reference conflict

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-popover

I'm working in a project that is been working with ngx-popover but it is limited for a specific case.

I want to keep working with both libs but im getting some conflicts because the implementation is so similar.

**Module**

```
import { PopoverModule } from "ngx-popover";
import { PopoverModule as PopoverBModule } from "ngx-bootstrap";
    imports: 
    [
       ...,
       PopoverModule,            
       PopoverBModule.forRoot(),          
    ],
```

**HTML ngx-bootstrap:**

```
<ng-template #popTemplate let-message="message">{{ message }}</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        [popover]="popTemplate" [popoverContext]="context" [outsideClick]="true">
  Open popover with custom context
</button>
```

**HTML ngx-popover:**

```
 <i[popover]="popId"></i>
    <popover-content
       #popId
       placement="above|auto"
       [animation]="true"
       [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
        ....
     </popover-content>
```

I dont have any compilation error the problem is when I  try to perform the ngx-bootstrap popover it is pointing directly to ngx-popover.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
>       at Popover.push../node_modules/ngx-popover/Popover.js.Popover.show (Popover.js:114)
>       at Popover.push../node_modules/ngx-popover/Popover.js.Popover.toggle
>   (Popover.js:67)
>       at Popover.push../node_modules/ngx-popover/Popover.js.Popover.showOrHideOnClick
>   (Popover.js:37)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (VimeoVideoListComponent.html:24)
>       at handleEvent (core.js:19628)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20722)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:20425)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.js:17077)
>       at core.js:17524
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.js:993)

The question is: **There is a way to force the directive [popover] point to ngx-bootstrap but just in this spesific case?**

by doing somethinlike **[PopoverBModule.popover]** it doesnt work LOL

Comment: Can you arround `popover.onCloseFromOutside.subscribe(function () { return _this.hide(); });` by a setTimeou 0 ? `setTimeout(() => { popover.onCloseFromOutside.subscribe(function () { return _this.hide(); }) }, 0);` It will wait that it's added to the HTML

Comment: I think I found the issue but Im doing research I have installed ngx-bootstrap Pop over and ngx-popover  I think i have name conflict with that modules and is pointing to different module. I will continue reaching

Comment: Yes it is the problem I will change the  question

Comment: You are right, do you really need to use the two libs in your module ?

Comment: I just updated the question. the project has alot of implementations of ngx-popover. but in particular case ngx-bootstrap works better. then I do not want to broke the code changing all the implementations

Comment: I think like said in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213094/angular-4-if-there-are-multiple-components-with-same-selector-how-to-load-onl , you must create an intermediary module that only imports the ngx-bootstrap one, extend the directive to give an other selector and export this new directive.

Comment: Wow, Excellent Idea !!  I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was create a module to import ngxbootstrap and my component, and just import the module instead import the VimeoVideoListComponent in the parent module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PopoverModule } from "ngx-bootstrap";
import { VimeoVideoListComponent } from './vimeo-video-list.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    VimeoVideoListComponent
  ],
  exports:[VimeoVideoListComponent],  
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PopoverModule.forRoot()    
  ]
})
export class VimeoVideoListModule { }
```

Thanks @Gilsdav